# Pal to NTSC Conversion

Tags: conversion

I'm in new territory here and was hoping someone out there might be able to help. I'm at the end of a 5.1 project that was mixed at 25fps and needed to be converted to 29.97fps. All the final mixes and stems have already been converted along with the pictures in another post house, however there was a glitch on one of the files so to avoid additional costs I said I'd try and convert the file myself
 A colleague said he had success with the following method converting from 25 to 24 fps: Importing the 5.1 mix stem into Protools, selecting sample rate conversion and ticking the (in my case) Pal to NTSC preset. However the synch is way off and the file length is over a minute too long. Does anybody have any solutions that don't involve software other than Protools? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a 4.1% pull down and bouncing out the new file. Then pull it back into the session (with pull down off - 0%) and compare the original with the new. If you see/hear a difference, then you're probably good. I've never had to do this myself, so I don't know if it will actually work that way, but it's worth a shot.

In your "Session Setup" window expand the "Time Code Settings" section. Look for "Audio Rate Pull Up/Down" and select "Down 4%, Down 0.1%".

I'm curious, so let us know if that works. You may also want to download MPEG Streamclip from [Squared5.com](http://www.squared5.com/) as a backup. It will do transcodes (even audio I believe), and it's free.